# Is it possible to use the configSource attributes on Custom ConfigurationElement classes in web.config?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, configsource

I know it's possible to reference external configuration files for a configuration section but I'd like to go one step further and reference config files from a configuration element.

i.e.

`<CustomConfigSection>

    <Plugins>

        <Plugin configSource="plugin.config"/>

        <Plugin configSource="another_plugin.config"/>

    </Plugins>

</CustomConfigSection>`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're referring to:
http://blogs.msdn.com/tomholl/archive/2006/04/02/entlib2externalconfig.aspx